# Subcategories cannot been seen on their me the route category on homepage

Tags: category

I made subcategories under my route categories on my Magento for some reason I cannot see them on my homepage.

Answer (score 0):

There might several reason Some of them are :

1. The categories not added as sub-categories of the Default, Root category.
2. The Magento store configuration has no default category set.
3. The category cache requires a refresh.
4. Must be  **Is Active = yes** and **Include in Navigation Menu  = yes**
   Hope it will help you.

[Also see here.](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/655-magento-categories-and-products-are-not-showing)